# How can I reset ubuntu gnome terminal options?

Tags: command-line, gnome, gnome-terminal, colors

I have Ubuntu gnome on my laptop and in my terminal all the text is green. However, on another computer my text is green but the bold text is a different color. I already changed the bold text on my laptop to another color but I guess the terminal is not printing bold.

How do I fix this? I don't remember changing options on the terminal where it does show bolded text so I'm thinking I can just reset my settings somewhere. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Two simple steps to reset `gnome-terminal` to defaults:

1. Run this command from your Terminal:

   ```
   mv -v $HOME/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/ $HOME/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal_bak
   ```
2. Log out and then log back in

The defaults will then be back in place. Then go to:

```
Edit --> Profile Preferences
```

and customise as you wish...

Comment: Hi,  it looks like it doesn't exist. I get this:

"mv: cannot stat ‘/home/cisko/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal’: No such file or directory"

Comment: The absence of this directory would normally indicate that you are using the defaults, although green does not sound right. I presume you are using the actual gnome-terminal?

Comment: I think I am using the gnome-terminal. I typed in 'ps -a | grep "terminal" ' and there is only one line "5991 tty2     00:00:00 gnome-terminal-"

It ends in a hyphen. Is that weird?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I'm answering it because no one answered and I ran into a problem with gnome terminal which I needed to reset it.

Gnome terminal can be reset by deleting this file **/home/.config/dconf/user**.
But this will reset every config of dconf, so be careful.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do that(*reset all gnome-terminal settings*) is from command-line in the terminal itself by simply running this command:

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/
```