# Gnome-Terminal Auto Close

Tags: command-line, gnome, gnome-terminal

I configured my terminal to run "bluetooth off" at start up and exit terminal after the command. Now the terminal opens, runs the command and closes instantly rendering me unable to run any more commands.

I have tried reinstalling the terminal application but the settings still remain the same. How can I restore the default terminal setting?

[image: Editing Preferences]

Comment: And how did you configure it ? Where did you place the command(s) ?

Comment: I changed the preferences for the terminal. :)

Comment: Ok, so it's in terminal settings, not .bashrc or .profile file, gotcha.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/755715/295286. See if this helps

Comment: did not solve the problem :(

I added a picture of what happened...if it helps! :)

Comment: May I ask why you did you add that command to terminal ? What is your goal ?

Comment: I was just playing around... trying to learn new things... and I always use the "bluetooth off" command for any kind of testing! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of ways to reset `gnome-terminal`. One has been suggested in the comments already : remove or move the `$HOME/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/` folder. Second approach would be to open Unity dash , search for `xterm` (which is a standard terminal emulator on almost any Linux) and run form there `gnome-terminal -e bash` which will open the shell instead of whatever command you specified. From there you should be able to reset the preferences.

Comment: I found this solution exactly at the same time that you posted.... this worked for me...

Thank you very very much.. :)

I would up vote your comment, but it says I need 15 rep.. :D

Comment: @Rokin Always glad to help :)  where did you find the solution by the way ?  For accepting answers , you don't need extra rep - just click the gray checkmark next to up and down arrows

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512055/avoid-gnome-terminal-close-after-script-execution#


Here! The guy named Lesmana with 52 up votes on his answer solved it :)

Comment: @Rokin ah, ok. If that would have been askubuntu question, we could have been able link the two questions together. Anyway, glad we've solved the issue :) Feel free to ask if you have more questions

Comment: sure!! Thanks for your help! Much appreciated!! :)